# Does OpenGL/DirectX converts other texture formats to RGBA format internally?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, directx

As title said, I have a dynamic texture (which is updated in every frame) from a RGB565 color buffer, I don't know which way will have better performance:

1. Creating a texture with RGB565 format and upload RGB565 color buffer to GPU in every frame.
2. Creating a texture with RGBA8888 format and convert RGB565 color buffer to RGBA8888 before upload to GPU.

I think if OpenGL/DirectX converts other formats to RGBA8888 internally, then the creating RGBA8888 texture and convert data myself before upload to GPU way may be faster.

Comment: implementation defined I guess, some would be able to handle different formats in the texture buffer

Answer (score 4):

Don't know which one is more performant?

**Benchmark it.**

That being said, 5-6-5 mode is this weird for a reason - it's exactly 16 bits. GPUs typically support all of those in hardware, so if a format is present, you can assume the hardware instructions for handling it are there.

Answer (score 1):

It also may depends on the global workload you put on your gpu, and on the gpu characteristics : Putting 565 texture onto video memory and reading back from this texture in a shader will consume half the memory bandwidth of the 888 counterpart, but it might (and not for sure) consume a bit more processing power.

So benchmark it, if possible on multiple configurations :)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that converting the RGB565 data to RGBA8888 yourself would ever be faster.

First of all, RGB565 is a format that's pretty widely used, and there is a high likelihood that your hardware supports it directly. If the precision is high enough for your use case, it will use half the memory of RGBA8888, and most likely be at least as efficient, due to the reduced memory bandwidth and correspondingly higher cache hit rates.

Even if the hardware does not support it, I still don't think converting it to RGBA8888 yourself will be more efficient. Any driver worth its money will have highly optimized code for format conversion. And even more importantly, it might be able to apply the format conversion during a data copy it will have to make anyway, which avoids one copy of the data compared to your code doing the conversion.